# Pulling data from multiple excel workbooks into a single sheet using SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro to pull data out of daily reports, the code below works for the data nested in row 16 and the second code works for the data nested in row 15 but not 16. I need the code to work for both rows.

```vb
Sub ImportDataFromSpecificCellsUsingADODB()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim day As Integer
    Dim monthIndex As Integer
    Dim months As Variant
    Dim yearPart As Integer
    Dim monthPart As Integer
    Dim dateValue As Date
    Dim cellAddressesRow16 As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cellData As Variant

    ' Base path to your local folder
    Dim strBasePath As String
    strBasePath = "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\OneDrive_1_12-18-2023\"

    ' Array of months to process
    months = Array("08-Aug", "09-Sep", "10-Oct", "11-Nov", "12-Dec")
    
    ' Year part (assuming all files are from 2023)
    yearPart = 2023

    ' Set target worksheet
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6") ' Change to your target sheet's name

    ' Clear existing data from the target sheet, below the first row
    wsTarget.Range("A2:Z" & wsTarget.Rows.Count).ClearContents

    ' Cell addresses to copy for row 16
    cellAddressesRow16 = Array("D16", "G16", "J16", "M16", "T16")

    ' Create ADO connection object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    ' Iterate over each month
    For monthIndex = 0 To UBound(months)
        monthPart = CInt(Left(months(monthIndex), 2)) ' Month part

        ' Loop through each day of the month
        For day = 1 To 31 ' Adjust for the number of days in each month
            filePath = strBasePath & months(monthIndex) & "\" & Format(day, "00") & "-" & Left(months(monthIndex), 2) & "-23.xlsx"
            If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then
                ' Connection string
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO';"
                conn.Open strConn

                ' Calculate the next available row in the target sheet
                lastRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                ' Create date from file name
                dateValue = DateSerial(yearPart, monthPart, day)

                ' Write date to target worksheet
                wsTarget.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = dateValue

                ' Reset cellData - dimension it to have the same number of elements as cellAddressesRow16
                ReDim cellData(0 To UBound(cellAddressesRow16))
            
                ' Retrieve data for each cell address in row 16
                For i = LBound(cellAddressesRow16) To UBound(cellAddressesRow16)
                    ' SQL to select data from a single cell in the "Day" sheet
                    strSQL = "SELECT F1 FROM [Day$" & cellAddressesRow16(i) & ":" & cellAddressesRow16(i) & "]"
            
                    ' Create recordset
                    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                    rs.Open strSQL, conn, 3, 1
            
                    If Not rs.EOF Then
                        cellData(i) = rs.Fields(0).Value
                    End If
            
                    rs.Close
                Next i
            
                ' Write data from row 16
                For i = 0 To UBound(cellAddressesRow16)
                    wsTarget.Cells(lastRow, 2 + i).Value = cellData(i)
                Next i
                ' Close connection
                conn.Close
            End If
        Next day
    Next monthIndex

    ' Clean up
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub



Sub ImportDataFromSpecificCellsUsingADODB()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim day As Integer
    Dim monthIndex As Integer
    Dim months As Variant
    Dim yearPart As Integer
    Dim monthPart As Integer
    Dim dateValue As Date
    Dim cellAddressesRow15 As Variant
    Dim cellAddressesRow16 As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cellData15 As Variant
    Dim cellData16 As Variant

    ' Base path to your local folder
    Dim strBasePath As String
    strBasePath = "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\OneDrive_1_12-18-2023\"

    ' Array of months to process
    months = Array("08-Aug", "09-Sep", "10-Oct", "11-Nov", "12-Dec")
    
    ' Year part (assuming all files are from 2023)
    yearPart = 2023

    ' Set target worksheet
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6") ' Change to your target sheet's name

    ' Clear existing data from the target sheet, below the first row
    wsTarget.Range("A2:Z" & wsTarget.Rows.Count).ClearContents

    ' Cell addresses to copy for rows 15 and 16
    cellAddressesRow15 = Array("D15", "G15", "J15", "M15", "N15", "T15")
    cellAddressesRow16 = Array("D16", "G16", "J16", "M16", "T16")

    ' Create ADO connection object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    ' Iterate over each month
    For monthIndex = 0 To UBound(months)
        monthPart = CInt(Left(months(monthIndex), 2)) ' Month part

        ' Loop through each day of the month
        For day = 1 To 31 ' Adjust for the number of days in each month
            filePath = strBasePath & months(monthIndex) & "\" & Format(day, "00") & "-" & Left(months(monthIndex), 2) & "-23.xlsx"
            If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then
                ' Connection string
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO';"
                conn.Open strConn

                ' Calculate the next available row in the target sheet
                lastRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                ' Create date from file name
                dateValue = DateSerial(yearPart, monthPart, day)

                ' Write date to target worksheet
                wsTarget.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = dateValue

                ' Reset and retrieve data for row 15
                ReDim cellData15(0 To UBound(cellAddressesRow15))
                For i = LBound(cellAddressesRow15) To UBound(cellAddressesRow15)
                    strSQL = "SELECT F1 FROM [Day$" & cellAddressesRow15(i) & ":" & cellAddressesRow15(i) & "]"
                    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                    rs.Open strSQL, conn, 3, 1
                    If Not rs.EOF Then
                        cellData15(i) = rs.Fields(0).Value
                    End If
                    rs.Close
                Next i

                ' Write data from row 15
                For i = 0 To UBound(cellAddressesRow15)
                    wsTarget.Cells(lastRow, 2 + i).Value = cellData15(i)
                Next i

                ' Reset and retrieve data for row 16
                ReDim cellData16(0 To UBound(cellAddressesRow16))
                For i = LBound(cellAddressesRow16) To UBound(cellAddressesRow16)
                    strSQL = "SELECT F1 FROM [Day$" & cellAddressesRow16(i) & ":" & cellAddressesRow16(i) & "]"
                    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                    rs.Open strSQL, conn, 3, 1
                    If Not rs.EOF Then
                        cellData16(i) = rs.Fields(0).Value
                    End If
                    rs.Close
                Next i

                ' Write data from row 16
                For i = 0 To UBound(cellAddressesRow16)
                    wsTarget.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2 + i).Value = cellData16(i)
                Next i

                ' Close connection
                conn.Close
            End If
        Next day
    Next monthIndex

    ' Clean up
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what’s the actual issue you are facing?